# how to set the size of the polar plot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

I have made the plot using python. I want to enlarge the diameter of the circle or enlarge the size of the figure. What code should I add?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.grid(False)

ax.set_rticks([])
for i in range(0,360,3):
    plt.arrow(i/180.*np.pi, 0, 0, 1, alpha = 0.75, width = 0.00001,ec = 'black', fc = 'blue', lw = 1.25)
plt.show()
```

Thank you

Comment: So do you want to change the radial range of your plot? Or just have a larger image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the circle already takes most of the space in the figure, it may not make too much sense to make it larger.

If the aim to better visualize the region around the center, you may

1. Decrease the linewidth of the arrows

   ```
   plt.arrow(... , lw = 0.4)
   ```
2. Increase the figure size

   ```
   fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
   ```

Comment: Your second solution is the best choice for me, thank's